# How to restore product key?

Tags: product-key

I am writing a mac app. I want to know how to save a product key is a relatively safe and reasonable way.

For example, the way to restore Microsoft Office product key(I do not know it). Keychain maybe safe, but it is easy to find on mac.Which has a good solution?

Comment: Your question need to be more specific.Try this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058156/encryption-product-keys-public-and-private-key-encryption

Comment: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."*

Answer (score 1):

NET supports public key encryption in various ways, such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867080.aspx. Having said this, all you'd gain is some confidence that someone with full access to the released code would not have the ability to issue their own product keys. None of this stops them from patching the client to accept anything as a valid key. That's where obfuscation fits in.
From [Encryption Product Keys : Public and Private key encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058156/encryption-product-keys-public-and-private-key-encryption)